# Saying Hello in the correct way

Tags: pronouns

May I say, hello it's Rana speaking, or I must say: Hello, I'm Rana speaking?
Thanks

Comment: Hi. Beginner-level questions would be better received on the [ell.se] site.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it should be migrated to ELL.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

> - Hello, Rana speaking
> - Hello. This is Rana